# Calculating a work week based on weekly time-sheet

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, formula, equation

I am trying to calculate work week hours which I want to match it with the company's paycheck earned amount. So far I have this:

```
7/12/2011   7.90
7/13/2011   8.03
7/14/2011   7.83
7/15/2011   7.97
7/18/2011   8.20
7/19/2011   8.12
7/20/2011   8.15
7/21/2011   6.07
7/22/2011   8.12
7/25/2011   8.13
7/26/2011   8.1
7/27/2011   8.4
7/29/2011   8.27
8/1/2011    8.33
8/2/2011    8.18
8/3/2011    8.22
8/4/2011    6.72
8/5/2011    7.57
8/8/2011    8.07
8/9/2011    8.28
8/10/2011   5.8
8/11/2011   8.8
8/15/2011   8.2
8/16/2011   7.95
8/17/2011   8.17
8/18/2011   8.1
8/19/2011   7.8
8/22/2011   8.18
8/23/2011   9.7
8/24/2011   8.17
8/25/2011   8.18
```

and want to match the total to this:

```
Check Date Earnings Start  Earnings End    Earn Type   Earn Amount
8/10/2011   7/26/2011   8/10/2011   Salary          899.6
8/25/2011   8/11/2011   8/25/2011   Salary          888.28
```

The company's pay period varies, that's why these days don't follow. 
So far I was using =SUMIFS functions but they are not giving the result I need.
Let me know if there's clarifications anyone needs!

Comment: First I want to return the amount hours worked during the pay period, then later I will sum up the money earned. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `=SUMIFS()` to get the hours during the pay period.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&F4,A:A,"<="&G4)
```

Here,

- column A contains the dates,
- column B contains the hours,
- cell F4 is the Earnings start date,
- cell G4 is the Earnings end date.